# Pip install fails with “connection error" for soaplib library installation

Tags: python, automation, pip, robotframework

When I try to install soaplib using pip command (pip install soaplib) its showing some error, like below

```
C:\Users\jojin.jose>pip install soaplib
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/soaplib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/soaplib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/soaplib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/soaplib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/soaplib/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/soaplib/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/soaplib/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement soaplib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for soaplib
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)'))) - skipping
```

How can I resolve this ?

OS : Windows 10 Enterprise, Python Version : Python 3.7.8, Pip Version : pip 20.2.3

Comment: Could be: corporate SSL interception, a problem with the server, some bad SSL setup on your machine or someone tries to attack your connect (same as 1. IMHO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install this program manually from https://pypi.org/project/soaplib/

Answer (score 0):

It most likely a network issue check your internet connection and make sure it connected then retry the pip install.

Comment: I have tried different networks and the result was same. If I try to install some other library using pip command its works without theses issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try bypassing the ssl cert

```
py -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org pygame -vvv
```

Comment: Please do not give answers that break security features without explicitly explaining the impact!

Comment: @KlausD. Do we have any other option to resolve this ? without breaking security.